# How to order bars in faceted ggplot2 bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, bar-chart

If I want to order the bars in a ggplot2 barchart from largest to smallest, then I'd usually update the factor levels of the bar category, like so

```
one_group <- data.frame(
  height   = runif(5),
  category = gl(5, 1)
)

o <- order(one_group$height, decreasing = TRUE)
one_group$category <- factor(one_group$category, levels = one_group$category[o])

p_one_group <- ggplot(one_group, aes(category, height)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
p_one_group
```

If have have several groups of barcharts that I'd like in different facets, with each facet having bars ordered from largest to smallest (and different x-axes) then the technique breaks down.

Given some sample data

```
two_groups <- data.frame(
  height   = runif(10),
  category = gl(5, 2),
  group    = gl(2, 1, 10, labels = letters[1:2])
)
```

and the plotting code

```
p_two_groups <- ggplot(two_groups, aes(category, height)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_grid(. ~ group, scales = "free_x")
p_two_groups
```

what do I need to do to get the bar ordering right?

If it helps, an equivalent problem to solve is: how do I update factor levels after I've done the faceting?

Comment: Nice question.  I can't immediately think of an answer, only alternatives. 1) Use align.plots in package ggExtra.  2) Construct separate, individual graphs and combine them using grid viewports - vplayout in ggExtra simplifies this.  If this seems useful, I can post an example in an answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

here is a hack:

```
two_groups <- transform(two_groups, category2 = factor(paste(group, category)))
two_groups <- transform(two_groups, category2 = reorder(category2, rank(height)))

ggplot(two_groups, aes(category2, height)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_grid(. ~ group, scales = "free_x") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=two_groups$category, breaks=two_groups$category2)
```

1. make **UNIQUE** factor variable for all entries (category2)
2. reorder the variable based on the height
3. plot on the variable: aes(x=category2)
4. re-label the axis using original value (category) for the variable (category2) in scale_x_discrete.

Comment: nice one kohske. this will go into my folder of code snippets!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a hack to achieve what you want. I was unable to figure out how to get the category values below the tick marks. So if someone can help fix that, it would be wonderful. Let me know if this works

```
# add a height rank variable to the data frame
two_groups = ddply(two_groups, .(group), transform, hrank = rank(height));

# plot the graph

p_two_groups <- ggplot(two_groups, aes(-hrank, height)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_grid(. ~ group, scales = "free_x") +
  opts(axis.text.x = theme_blank()) +
  geom_text(aes(y = 0, label = category, vjust = 1.5))
```

Comment: Nice `ddply`/`transform` combo.  I don't think that `geom_text` works outside the plotting panels; overriding the scale as per kohske's answer is a cleaner fix.

Comment: yup. i was unable to figure out how to overcome that limitation. great hack from kohske.