# R setting space between graphs on a multiplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, viewport

Following a previous R post [Specifying ggplot2 panel width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489250/specifying-ggplot2-panel-width), I have been able to produce this plot:

[image]

[with this code.](http://ubuntuone.com/2mmwKjtMW46RvGL3V6J9ur)

You can find the output of dput(datos) at http://ubuntuone.com/0Nlb97mOeDhSbFrbFKCeEG

Now my question is how can I remove/reduce the white space between the graphs. I have found examples with ggExtra package, ggplot and facet, multiplots with options as plot.margin or panel.margin but couldn't find how to apply to my case.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: I have just noticed that plots have not the same width. It is needed they have the same width so they can share x axis labels from bottom plot.

Answer (score 7):

Using `xlab(NULL)` instead of `xlab(" ")` will remove some space off the bottom of each plot.

Using `opts(plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0), "cm"))` will remove a little space from the edges.

---

I think that your have overcomplicated things by creating 5 separate graphs and recombining them.  Faceting is much easier.

```
mdatos <- melt(datos[, -1], id.vars = "dia")
(p_all <- ggplot(mdatos, aes(dia, value)) +
  geom_line(colour = "blue") +
  facet_grid(variable ~ ., scale = "free_y") +
  xlab("Day") +
  ylab(NULL) 
)
```

---

The plot panels aren't the same width because some y axis labels have three digit numbers, and some only two.  Either change the formatting of the y axis, or use my facetting suggestion.

Comment: Hi Richie, I have tried your suggestion and have not noticed significant change in the plot

Comment: @pacomet: The difference is subtle. Turn on plot history (in the RGui plot window History -> Recording) and Page Up/Down to compare.  Or use facetting, which will give you minimal spaces.

Comment: As a newbie maybe I have overcomplicated. I had created separated graphs for another purpose and then decided to try combining. I had tried facetting before as you suggest from a previous post and have another question. Here, `ggplot` uses geom_line for all 5 graphs but I want the one at the bottom uses geom_bar(). Is it possible in this case? Thanks again.

Comment: @pacomet: Different geoms in different facets is a big enough problem that it deserves it's own question.

Comment: @pacomet: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903972/can-you-specify-different-geoms-for-different-facets-in-a-ggplot/7904058

Answer (score 2):

You can layout and control the margins of several subplots with `par` and `layout`. For example:

```
  par (fig=c(0,1,0,1), # Figure region in the device display region (x1,x2,y1,y2)
       omi=c(0,0,0.3,0), # global margins in inches (bottom, left, top, right)
       mai=c(0.1,0.1,0.3,0.1)) # subplot margins in inches (bottom, left, top, right)
  layout(matrix(1:4, 2, 2, byrow = TRUE))
```

Comment: For base graphics, yes.  This won't work for grid based plots like those created in ggplot2.