# Can you specify different geoms for different facets in a ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do you specify different geoms for different facets in a ggplot?

(Asked on behalf of @pacomet, who [wanted to know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901925/r-setting-space-between-graphs-on-a-multiplot/7902621#7902621).)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

here is another approach by subsetting data:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + facet_wrap(~cyl) + 
  geom_point(data = subset(mtcars, cyl == 4)) +
  geom_line(data = subset(mtcars, cyl == 6)) +
  geom_text(data = subset(mtcars, cyl == 8), aes(label = gear))
```

[image]

Comment: you can simplify the code a bit by using `subset = .(cyl == 4)` instead of using the `data` call.

Comment: function `.` is from package `plyr` but I don't think it's working anymore

Comment: An alternative in recent versions of `ggplot` is to use `data = ~subset(.x, cyl == 4)`

Answer (score 3):

Here's some sample data with 5 groups (`g`).  We want a different geom type in the fifth facet.  Notice the trick of creating two different versions of the `y` variable, one for the first four facets, and one for the fifth.

```
dfr <- data.frame(
  x = rep.int(1:10, 5),
  y = runif(50),
  g = gl(5, 10)
)
dfr$is.5 <- dfr$g == "5"
dfr$y.5 <- with(dfr, ifelse(is.5, y, NA)) 
dfr$y.not.5 <- with(dfr, ifelse(is.5, NA, y))
```

If the different geoms can use the same aesthetics (like point and lines), then it isn't a problem.

```
(p1 <- ggplot(dfr) +
  geom_line(aes(x, y.not.5)) +
  geom_point(aes(x, y.5)) +
  facet_grid(g ~ .)
)
```

However, a line plot and a bar chart require different facets, so they don't work toegther as expected.

```
(p2 <- ggplot(dfr) +
  geom_line(aes(x, y.not.5)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y.5)) +
  facet_grid(g ~ .)
)
```

In this case it is better to draw two separate graphs, and perhaps combine them with `Viewport`.