# customizing strip of grids in ggplot2 in rpy2

Tags: python, ggplot2, rpy2

I'm trying to change the background colors of strips on top of facet grids/facet wraps in ggplot2 and also remove their bounding boxes (i.e. just show the labels). It seems that this require `element_rect` which is not defined in rpy2 -- how can its constructor be defined? Or is there an alternative way of doing this without `element_rect`? I tried:

```
my_plot += theme(**{'strip.background': element_blank()})
```

but it does not work, giving the error:

```
rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in (function (el, elname)  : 
  Element panel.background must be a element_rect object.
```

also,

```
from rpy2.robjects.lib.ggplot2 import element_rect
```

fails with an import error. how can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[edit: added unspecified named parameters passed to `new()` in answer to comments for the answer]

Pretty much the same answer as in 
[how can theme_classic be accessed in rpy2 from ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18540397/how-can-theme-classic-be-accessed-in-rpy2-from-ggplot2) , and since I am it I'll add the note that problems in rpy2 that one want to be eventually solved should be reported to the issue tracker.

```
import rpy2.robjects.lib.ggplot2 as ggplot2

class ElementRect(ggplot2.Element):
    _constructor = ggplot2.ggplot2.element_rect
    @classmethod
    def new(cls, **kwargs):
        res = cls(cls._constructor(**kwargs))
        return res

# Monkey patch ggplot2
ggplot2.element_rect = ElementRect.new
```

Comment: If I do that it fails to accept the `fill=` argument: `'strip.background': ggplot2.element_rect(fill="white")}) ->
TypeError: new() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fill'`

Comment: same behaviour occurs with `colour` or these arguments http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/element_rect.html

Comment: Just add the arguments to the signature of the classmethod `new', as it is done for ElementText (https://bitbucket.org/lgautier/rpy2/src/ed79a71b7d8da5fa9857365890b9cdc572e183b1/rpy/robjects/lib/ggplot2.py?at=default#cl-661), and submit a patch when done.

Comment: The fix is in the repository, and will be included in rpy2 >= 2.3.7 .