# How to place grobs with annotation_custom() at precise areas of the plot region?

Tags: r, ggplot2, grob

I am trying to reproduce the following [base R] plot with **ggplot2**

[image]

I have managed most of this, but what is currently baffling me is the placement of the line segments that join the marginal rug plot on the right of the plot with the respective label. The labels have been draw (in the second figure below) via `anotation_custom()` and I have used @baptiste's trick of turning off clipping to allow drawing in the plot margin.

Despite many attempts I am unable to place `segmentGrobs()` at the desired locations in the device such that they join the correct rug tick and label.

A reproducible example is

```
y <- data.frame(matrix(runif(30*10), ncol = 10))
names(y) <- paste0("spp", 1:10)
treat <- gl(3, 10)
time <- factor(rep(1:10, 3))

require(vegan); require(grid); require(reshape2); require(ggplot2)
mod <- prc(y, treat, time)
```

If you don't have **vegan** installed, I append a `dput` of the fortified object at the end of the Question and a `fortify()` method should you wish to run the example and `fortify()` for handy plotting with `ggplot()`. I also include a somewhat lengthy function, `myPlt()`, that illustrates what I have working so far, which can be used on the example data set if you have the packages loaded and can create `mod`.

I have tried quite a few options but I seem to be flailing in the dark now on getting the line segments placed correctly.

I am not looking for a solution to the specific issue of plotting the labels/segments for the example data set, but a generic solution that I can use to place segments and labels programatically as this will form the basis of an `autoplot()` method for objects of `class(mod)`. I have the labels worked out OK, just not the line segments. So to the questions:

1. How are the `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin`, `ymax` arguments used when I want to place a segment grob containing a line running from data coord `x0`, `y0` to `x1`, `y1`?
2. Perhaps asked a different way, how do you use `annotation_custom()` to draw segments **outside** the plot region between known data coords `x0`, `y0` to `x1`, `y1`?

I would be happy to receive Answers that simply had any old plot in the plot region but showed how to add line segments between known coordinates *in the margin of the plot*.

I'm not wedded to the use of `annotation_custom()` so if a better solution is available I'd consider that too. I do want to *avoid* having the labels in the plot region though; I think I can achieve that by using `annotate()` and extending the x-axis limits in the scale via the `expand` argument.

### The `fortify()` method

```
fortify.prc <- function(model, data, scaling = 3, axis = 1,
                        ...) {
    s <- summary(model, scaling = scaling, axis = axis)
    b <- t(coef(s))
    rs <- rownames(b)
    cs <- colnames(b)
    res <- melt(b)
    names(res) <- c("Time", "Treatment", "Response")
    n <- length(s$sp)
    sampLab <- paste(res$Treatment, res$Time, sep = "-")
    res <- rbind(res, cbind(Time = rep(NA, n),
                            Treatment = rep(NA, n),
                            Response = s$sp))
    res$Score <- factor(c(rep("Sample", prod(dim(b))),
                          rep("Species", n)))
    res$Label <- c(sampLab, names(s$sp))
    res
}
```

### The `dput()`

This is the output from `fortify.prc(mod)`:

```
structure(list(Time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), Treatment = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Response = c(0.775222658013234, 
-0.0374860102875694, 0.100620532505619, 0.17475403767196, -0.736181209242918, 
1.18581913245908, -0.235457236665258, -0.494834646295896, -0.22096700738071, 
-0.00852429328460645, 0.102286976108412, -0.116035743892094, 
0.01054849999509, 0.429857364190398, -0.29619258318138, 0.394303081010858, 
-0.456401545475929, 0.391960511587087, -0.218177702859661, -0.174814586471715, 
0.424769871360028, -0.0771395073436865, 0.698662414019584, 0.695676522106077, 
-0.31659375422071, -0.584947748238806, -0.523065304477453, -0.19259357510277, 
-0.0786143714402391, -0.313283220381509), Score = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Sample", 
"Species"), class = "factor"), Label = c("2-1", "2-2", "2-3", 
"2-4", "2-5", "2-6", "2-7", "2-8", "2-9", "2-10", "3-1", "3-2", 
"3-3", "3-4", "3-5", "3-6", "3-7", "3-8", "3-9", "3-10", "spp1", 
"spp2", "spp3", "spp4", "spp5", "spp6", "spp7", "spp8", "spp9", 
"spp10")), .Names = c("Time", "Treatment", "Response", "Score", 
"Label"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
"20", "spp1", "spp2", "spp3", "spp4", "spp5", "spp6", "spp7", 
"spp8", "spp9", "spp10"), class = "data.frame")
```

### What I've tried:

```
myPlt <- function(x, air = 1.1) {
    ## fortify PRC model
    fx <- fortify(x)
    ## samples and species scores
    sampScr <- fx[fx$Score == "Sample", ]
    sppScr <- fx[fx$Score != "Sample", ]
    ord <- order(sppScr$Response)
    sppScr <- sppScr[ord, ]
    ## base plot
    plt <- ggplot(data = sampScr,
                  aes(x = Time, y = Response,
                      colour = Treatment, group = Treatment),
                  subset = Score == "Sample")
    plt <- plt + geom_line() + # add lines
            geom_rug(sides = "r", data = sppScr) ## add rug
    ## species labels
    sppLab <- sppScr[, "Label"]
    ## label grobs
    tg <- lapply(sppLab, textGrob, just = "left")
    ## label grob widths
    wd <- sapply(tg, function(x) convertWidth(grobWidth(x), "cm",
                                              valueOnly = TRUE))
    mwd <- max(wd) ## largest label

    ## add some space to the margin, move legend etc
    plt <- plt +
        theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0, mwd + 1, 0, 0), "cm"),
              legend.position = "top",
              legend.direction = "horizontal",
              legend.key.width = unit(0.1, "npc"))
    ## annotate locations
    ##  - Xloc = new x coord for label
    ##  - Xloc2 = location at edge of plot region where rug ticks met plot box
    Xloc <- max(fx$Time, na.rm = TRUE) +
        (2 * (0.04 * diff(range(fx$Time, na.rm = TRUE))))
    Xloc2 <- max(fx$Time, na.rm = TRUE) +
        (0.04 * diff(range(fx$Time, na.rm = TRUE)))
    ## Yloc - where to position the labels in y coordinates
    yran <- max(sampScr$Response, na.rm = TRUE) -
        min(sampScr$Response, na.rm = TRUE)
    ## This is taken from vegan:::linestack
    ## attempting to space the labels out in the y-axis direction
    ht <- 2 * (air * (sapply(sppLab,
                        function(x) convertHeight(stringHeight(x),
                                                  "npc", valueOnly = TRUE)) *
                 yran))
    n <- length(sppLab)
    pos <- numeric(n)
    mid <- (n + 1) %/% 2
    pos[mid] <- sppScr$Response[mid]
    if (n > 1) {
        for (i in (mid + 1):n) {
            pos[i] <- max(sppScr$Response[i], pos[i - 1] + ht[i])
        }
    }
    if (n > 2) {
        for (i in (mid - 1):1) {
            pos[i] <- min(sppScr$Response[i], pos[i + 1] - ht[i])
        }
    }
    ## pos now contains the y-axis locations for the labels, spread out

    ## Loop over label and add textGrob and segmentsGrob for each one
    for (i in seq_along(wd)) {
        plt <- plt + annotation_custom(tg[[i]],
                                       xmin = Xloc,
                                       xmax = Xloc,
                                       ymin = pos[i],
                                       ymax = pos[i])
        seg <- segmentsGrob(Xloc2, pos[i], Xloc, pos[i])

        ## here is problem - what to use for ymin, ymax, xmin, xmax??
        plt <- plt + annotation_custom(seg,
                                       ## xmin = Xloc2,
                                       ## xmax = Xloc,
                                       ## ymin = pos[i],
                                       ## ymax = pos[i])
                                       xmin = Xloc2,
                                       xmax = Xloc,
                                       ymin = min(pos[i], sppScr$Response[i]),
                                       ymax = max(pos[i], sppScr$Response[i]))
    }
    ## Build the plot
    p2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(plt))
    ## turn off clipping
    p2$layout$clip[p2$layout$name=="panel"] <- "off"
    ## draw plot
    grid.draw(p2)
}
```

### Figure based on what I have tried in `myPlt()`

This is as far as I have made it with `myPlt()` from above. Note the small horizontal ticks drawn through the labels - these should be the angled line segments in the first figure above.

[image]

Comment: I don't think `annotation_custom` and turning off clipping are a good way to go. Have you considered [this sort of example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17371177/471093) instead?

Comment: Thanks @baptiste I hadn't (well I had considered the general idea of two plots arranged on a viewport, but discounted that at first as I thought the legend on one plot would make it hard to line up the two plots.) I'll take a look at the example you link to. I'd still like to understand how `annotation_custom()` works though. Assume I want to place a line segment within the plot region joining two known coordinates. I know how to do that with `annotate` but not with `annotation_custom()`. I don't grasp the difference.

Comment: If you are open to a different solution with nicely arranged labels inside the plot area, consider this answer with ggrepel. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45631834/4927395

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe this can illustrate `annotation_custom`,

```
myGrob <- grobTree(rectGrob(gp=gpar(fill="red", alpha=0.5)),
                   segmentsGrob(x0=0, x1=1, y0=0, y1=1, default.units="npc"))

myGrob2 <- grobTree(rectGrob(gp=gpar(fill="blue", alpha=0.5)),
                   segmentsGrob(x0=0, x1=1, y0=0, y1=1, default.units="npc"))

p <- qplot(1:10, 1:10) + theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0, 3, 0, 0), "cm")) +
  annotation_custom(myGrob, xmin=5, xmax=6, ymin=3.5, ymax=5.5) +
  annotate("segment", x=5, xend=6, y=3, yend=5, colour="red") +
  annotation_custom(myGrob2, xmin=8, xmax=12, ymin=3.5, ymax=5.5) 

p

g <- ggplotGrob(p)
g$layout$clip[g$layout$name=="panel"] <- "off"
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

There's a weird bug apparently, whereby if I reuse `myGrob` instead of `myGrob2`, it ignores the placement coordinates the second time and stacks it up with the first layer. This function is really buggy.

Comment: really?? either I misread the question (and would have downvoted it:), or you forgot about the bit that goes "if a better solution is available I'd consider that too"

Comment: I did consider it. I was especially confused about the grob placement. I think *both* answers are great, but this essentially resolves my issue of how to place grobs, which is the title of the Q. I was operating under a presumption on my part as to how to place the grobs, a presumption that was wrong. Not sure what grounds you'd have to downvote - not being the way you'd do things is not grounds for downvoting here.

Comment: joking - I just profoundly _dislike_ the bugs in `annotation_custom` and the hacky clip-off trick. Both of which I am guilty of having introduced in the first place.

Comment: Maybe I should downvote something of yours as penance for both "features"? ;-)

Answer (score 24):

Here's how I would approach this,

```
library(gtable)
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)

set.seed(1)
d <- data.frame(x=rep(1:10, 5),
                y=rnorm(50),
                g = gl(5,10))

# example plot
p <- ggplot(d, aes(x,y,colour=g)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0))+
  theme(legend.position="top",
        plot.margin=unit(c(1,0,0,0),"line"))

# dummy data for the legend plot
# built with the same y axis (same limits, same expand factor)
d2 <- ddply(d, "g", summarise, x=0, y=y[length(y)])
d2$lab <- paste0("line #", seq_len(nrow(d2)))

plegend <- ggplot(d, aes(x,y, colour=g)) +
  geom_blank() +
  geom_segment(data=d2, aes(x=2, xend=0, y=y, yend=y), 
               arrow=arrow(length=unit(2,"mm"), type="closed")) +
  geom_text(data=d2, aes(x=2.5,label=lab), hjust=0) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
  guides(colour="none")+
  theme_minimal() + theme(line=element_blank(),
                          text=element_blank(),
                          panel.background=element_rect(fill="grey95", linetype=2))

# extract the panel only, we don't need the rest
gl <- gtable_filter(ggplotGrob(plegend), "panel")

# add a cell next to the main plot panel, and insert gl there
g <- ggplotGrob(p)
index <- subset(g$layout, name == "panel")
g <- gtable_add_cols(g, unit(1, "strwidth", "line # 1") + unit(1, "cm"))
g <- gtable_add_grob(g, gl, t = index$t, l=ncol(g), 
                     b=index$b, r=ncol(g))
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

It should be straight-forward to adapt the "legend" plot with specific tags and locations (left as an exercise for the interested reader).

Comment: note: this is _not_ an incentive to break the law about secondary axes. They're still illegal.