# How to locate variable value in each panel of facet_grid and draw a trendline to connect them?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I have an issue about to draw a trendline in between each panel of in `facet_grid` and want to label `variable` values as shown like this;

[image]

same as other varibles you can imagine. How can we do that ?

here is my `df` and `ggplot` code to create this density facet_grid without tracing lines

```
fidel <- rep(seq(-30,30,30),each=5)
resp <- replicate(3,c(sort(10^runif(5,-6,0),decreasing=TRUE), sort(10^runif(5,-4,0),decreasing=TRUE),sort(10^runif(5,-2,0),decreasing=TRUE)))
Wdd <- rep(seq(1:5),times=3)
df <-   data.frame(fidel,resp,Wdd)

library(reshape2)   #for wide to long format
df_new <- melt(df,id=c("fidel","Wdd"))  

ggplot(df_new, aes(x=value,fill=factor(Wdd)))+
  geom_density(alpha=.5,adjust=0.5)+
  scale_x_log10(breaks = c(1e-5,1e-3,1e-1,1),limits = c(1e-6,1))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,1,0.2),limits=c(0,1))+
  facet_grid(fidel~Wdd,scales="free_x")+
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

Comment: Have you tried something for exampled based on this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31690007/ggplot-drawing-line-between-points-across-facets ?

Comment: @lukeA i just checked that link. But it seems very complicated way. There should be a much elegant way I guess..

Comment: I guess not. :-) (So my 1st thought was: Better do it with InkScape in 3 Minutes, if it's a one time report, than getting too hack'ish with grid.) But let's see.

Comment: @lukeA its not a one tıme report or homework. I just provide here three `varible` but in real data ı have 100 `varible`. So I need to automated plot for selected `varible` to plot trendline to find out how this variables scattered between grids. So inkscape solution wont work for me.

Comment: As I said: trying to draw lines between facets probably is not worth the effort. Stay with just marking the points, which is relatively easy.

Comment: @lukeA so how can I mark the points? with the link that you suggested?

Comment: To annotate facets (e.g. with custom text and points), have a look here https://www.google.com/search?q=ggplot+annovate+facets

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32158374/draw-lines-between-two-different-grid-arranged-plots) gtable approach in the answer by baptiste?

Comment: at least can somebody answer with using reproducible `df` here?

Comment: Easiest workaround might be not to use facetting along rows, but simply offset the data vertically