# Scale ggplot2 plot margins to fit text grob

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is my plot:

[image: Plot]

If you look to the right y axis, you see that the text has been cut due to the margin. The textgrobs on the right side y axis are annotation_custom's. Is there some way to automatically adjust the margin to fit both the plot and all the textgrobs?

Comment: I wouldn't use annotation_custom for this; better make another plot and extract its plot panel to add to the gtable https://stackoverflow.com/a/17493256/471093

Comment: That plot would end up using annotation_custom, too

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.