# Combine phylogenetic tree with x,y graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra, phylogeny, ape-phylo

I'm trying to arrange a phylogenetic tree onto a graph showing physiological data for a set of related organisms.  Something like the picture below.  This was put together in powerpoint from 2 separate graphs.  I guess it gets the job done, but I was hoping to create a single image which I think will be easier to format into a document.  I am able to produce the graph I want using ggplot2, and import the tree using ape.  I was thinking there should be a way to save the tree as a graphical object and then arrange it with the graph using the gridarrange function in gridExtra.  The problem is that ape won't let me save the tree as a graphical object, e.g.,

```
p2<-plot(tree, dir = "u", show.tip.label = FALSE)
```

just plots the tree and when you call p2 it just gives a list of arguments.  I'm wondering if anyone has any tips.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: looks [similar to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370853/align-ggplot2-plots-vertically/17371177#17371177)

Comment: To clarify: Your top image comes from ggplot, while the phylogenetic tree is drawn using the base plotting system. So you want to combine a ggplot, and base plot, on the same image. I think the answer, if there is one, will be more trouble than its worth.

Comment: Top image would come from ggplot2, tree from ape.  If there is some way of importing a tree into ggplot2 that would be fine, I'm just not aware of it.

Comment: The `gridBase` package has facilities for mixing `grid` and `base` graphics. `gggplot2` is one form of `grid` graphics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if that will work with gtable from CRAN

```
require(ggplot2)
require(gridBase)
require(gtable)

p <- qplot(1,1)
g <- ggplotGrob(p)

g <- gtable_add_rows(g, unit(2,"in"), nrow(g))
g <- gtable_add_grob(g, rectGrob(),
                     t = 7, l=4, b=7, r=4)

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)

#grid.force()
#grid.ls(grobs=F, viewports=T)
seekViewport("layout.7-4-7-4")
par(plt=gridPLT(), new=TRUE)
plot(rtree(10), "c", FALSE, direction = "u")
upViewport()
```

[image]

Comment: This works pretty well but do you know how to remove the black border around the bottom table?

Comment: not sure, but you can always set the rectGrob to use a transparent colour

Comment: I tried "g <- gtable_add_grob(g, rectGrob(gp = gpar(fill = "white"),
                     t = 7, l=4, b=7, r=4))"
but get an error.  Sorry, I'm not at all familiar with gtable

Comment: you should close the paren earlier; also, you want col="white"

Answer (score 1):

first I'd like to thanks [baptiste](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471093/baptiste) for ALL his multiple answers that solved most of my issues with ggplot2.

second, I had a similar question which was to include a tree from ape *inside* a heatmap obtained with ggplot2. Baptiste made my day, and though my simplified version could help.
I used only what was useful for me (removing the addition of gg_rows).

```
library(ape)
tr <- read.tree("mytree.tree")
# heat is the heatmap ggplot, using geom_tile
g <- ggplotGrob(heat)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
# use oma to reduce the tree so it fits 
par(new = TRUE, oma = c(5, 4, 5, 38))
plot(tr)
nodelabels(tr$node.label, cex = 1, frame = "none", col = "black", adj = c(-0.3, 0.5))
add.scale.bar()
# use dev.copy2pdf and not ggsave
dev.copy2pdf(file = "heatmap_prob.pdf")
```

the result is here 
[image: heatmaptree]