# drawing heatmap with dendrogram along with sample labels

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, cluster-analysis, dendrogram

Using the `heatmap` function of `made4`, I made this heatmap dendrogram from the example file:

```
data(khan)
heatplot(khan$train[1:30,], lowcol="blue", highcol="red")
```

How can I add a panel of labels for the samples on the edges of the heatmap, like in this figure?

[image]

The labels in this case are the squares that are adjacent to the heatmap first col and top row, used to denote a label for each sample so that one can see if the labels correspond with the clustering shown by the heatmap/dendrogram. In this particular plot they chose to make those labels correspond exactly to the colors of the dendrogram clusters but it doesn't have to be this way, I'm looking for way to just add a generic column and row of labels to the samples which might not correspond to the clustering resulting from applying a particular threshold of the dendrogram.

The `heatmap` function and the `khan` data is from `made4`:

```
require(made4)
```

see http://www.bioinf.ucd.ie/people/aedin/R/pages/made4/html/heatplot.html

I'm happy to use alternatives to `heatplot` that can draw the same thing, a heatmap with two dendrograms along the side based on hierarchical clustering. `heatplot` is just an example.

When I try `heatmap.2` like @HeatherTurner suggested I get this image (not sure how to turn off row/column labels on matrix to make it less clustered):

[image]

The heatmap looks corrupted. Here's code that reproduces this with a small data set:

```
require(gplots)
data(khan)
heatmap.2(as.matrix(khan$train[1:30,])
```

which generates this:
[image]

What is causing these corrupted looking heatmaps?

*update*: apologies, I think the heatmaps are not corrupted it's just the `trace` column is on which causes the cyan line to be drawn through heatmap. setting `trace=none` resolves the issue.

ps it looks like `heatmap` has `RowSideCols`, which might be same argument?

Comment: You will probably have to explain where the function `heatplot` is from, and possibly where the `khan` data came from as well. (I can't seem to find either.)

Comment: @joran: it's `made4`, added clarification, thanks

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Not on CRAN.

Comment: @joran: I'm happy to use some thing other than heatplot if it can draw the same thing, that's just the easiest thing I found

Comment: if you want to use ggplot2, maybe [this helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370853/align-ggplot2-plots-vertically/17371177#17371177) (I never know what those rooty things mean)

Comment: @baptiste: always prefer ggplot! thanks. which rooty things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `heatmap.2` function from the `gplots` package, which has arguments `RowSideColors` and `ColSideColors` to create side bars.

If this doesn't meet your needs, the `heatmap.plus` package allows further customisation, such as multiple colour side bars.

Comment: see my edits. I think `heatmap` has the same argument you refer to from `gplots` and `heatmap.2` does not work for me for some reason - it gives a messed up image

Answer (score 0):

There is a new package called 'fheatmap' in R .

[cpan fheatmap](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fheatmap/index.html)

I couldn't post image as I am new to blog.But check out examples in the manual.