# How to put labels on tiles in ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2, diagram

Functions `geom_tile` and `scale_fill_gradient` produce nice heatmaps. How to add labels to `ggplot2` tiles, so that each tile has its respective value printed over it?

PS: There're many packages that do heatmaps with vairous degree of success (e.g., a survey is here: [drawing heatmap with dendrogram along with sample labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17860120/drawing-heatmap-with-dendrogram-along-with-sample-labels)). But I'm interested in `ggplot2` solution, if possible.

A small code example (without labels):

```
library(Hmisc)
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(row=sample(c("A", "B"), 10, replace=T),
                 col=sample(c("x", "y"), 10, replace=T),
                 val=rnorm(10))
sdf <- summaryBy(val~row+col, data=df, FUN=mean)
ggplot(sdf, aes(x=row, y=col)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = val.mean), colour = "white") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "yellow")
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just:

```
+geom_text(aes(label=val.mean))
```