# ggplot grobs align with tableGrob

Tags: ggplot2, gridextra, gtable

I'm having difficulty to find solution for aligning ggplot grob and table grob. I tried to follow the instruction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370853/align-ggplot2-plots-vertically/17371177#17371177) but still didn't give the results I wanted.

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
library(gtable)
dat <- tibble::rownames_to_column(mtcars, "car") #convert rownames to first col

plot1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(car, mpg)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    coord_flip()

g1 <- ggplotGrob(plot1)
tb1 <- tableGrob(dat$cyl)
g1 <- gtable_add_cols(g1, unit(0.2, "npc"))
g1 <- gtable_add_grob(g1, grobs = tb1, t=3, l=ncol(g1), b=6, r=ncol(g1))

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g1)
```

I would like that each cell in the table be aligned to related bar in histogram, but still couldn't understand how the t,l,b,r be implemented from the layout.[This is the output I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XThu.png)

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a similar question as above when trying to make something like a forestplot in R using ggplot2 and didn't find any of the other solutions fit my needs. The answer above didn't work for me - the table didn't show up. So I hacked together a codewise not that pretty solution, but I actually kind of like the cleanliness visual output.

The things I like about this solution are:

- I aligned a set of custom text not in a table, but just in a figure on the right, where the alignment matched for each text entry and each label in the figure.
- I used a centered ggtitle to align a "column heading" above each set of text. These could be strings of any kind (in my actual use, I had point estimates and confidence intervals).

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(
    label = c("A", "B", "C"),
    point_est = c(1,2,3),
    lb_ci = c(.5, 1.5, 2.5),
    ub_ci = c(1.5, 2.5, 3.5),
    n = c(50, 100, 150),
    total = c(75, 150, 200)
)

plot1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=point_est, y=label)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin=lb_ci, xmax=ub_ci), height=.5) +
    ggtitle("Some measure") +
    ylab(NULL) + xlab("some effect estimate")

tab_base <- ggplot(dat, aes(y=label)) +
    ylab(NULL) + xlab("  ") + 
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=12), ## centering title on text
        axis.text.x=element_text(color="white"), ## need text to be printed so it stays aligned with figure but white so it's invisible
        axis.line=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),legend.position="none",
        panel.background=element_blank(),panel.border=element_blank(),panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),plot.background=element_blank())

tab1 <- tab_base + 
    geom_text(aes(x=1, label=n)) + 
    ggtitle("n")

tab2 <- tab_base +
    geom_text(aes(x=1, label=total)) + 
    ggtitle("total")

lay <-  matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3), nrow=1)
grid.arrange(plot1, tab1, tab2, layout_matrix = lay)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution!

Comment: Just wanted to thank you for posting this solution @Nicholas G Reich. I spent hours looking for a solution for a table that aligned perfectly with the graph. So grateful for this!

Answer (score 3):

By default the cell heights have absolute sizes to accommodate the text, but you [can change them to relative units](https://github.com/baptiste/gridextra/wiki/tableGrob#further-gtable-processing-and-integration) so that they scale with the plot panel,

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
library(gtable)
dat <- tibble::rownames_to_column(mtcars, "car") #convert rownames to first col

plot1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(car, mpg)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip()

g1 <- ggplotGrob(plot1)
tb1 <- tableGrob(dat$cyl, theme = ttheme_default(10))
tb1$heights = unit(rep(1/(nrow(tb1)), nrow(tb1)), "npc")
tb1$widths = unit.pmax(tb1$widths, unit(2, "lines"))
g1 <- gtable_add_cols(g1, sum(tb1$widths))
g1 <- gtable_add_grob(g1, grobs = tb1, t=6, l=ncol(g1), b=6, r=ncol(g1))

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the guidence, but I still don't understand why t=6 and b=6. When I look at the layout with `gtable_show_layout(g1)` the cell is (3,6)

Comment: I see now that you didn't use the same plot1 figure I'm using which gives different layout. Thanks again for explanation

Comment: Do you mind to share your code for plot1 with axis title x on top? I have difficulty to replicate the solution with axis title and ticks on the bottom og the plot.

Comment: When I run this code, I get a blank space on the RHS of the plot, unlike the plot shown above. Perhaps some update to one of the packages has made this not work anymore?