# How to add a side table to a Forest Plot in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Can you help with adding a side table to a Forest Plot I have made in ggplot2?

I tried Google but that didn't solve my problem.

My variables are

```
datasheet = d
d$author = name of the study
d$number = study size (number of patients)
d$treat = number of treatments
d$hr_l = lower CI
d$hr_u = upper CI
```

I wrote

```
fp <- ggplot(data=d, aes(x=author, y=treat, ymin=d$hr_l, ymax=d$hr_u))+
      geom_linerange(size=8, colour="#222a37", alpha=0.4) +
      geom_hline(aes(yintercept=4.27), lty=2, colour="black") +
      geom_point(size=3, shape=21, fill="darkred", alpha=0.4, 
      colour = "darkred", stroke = 1) +
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(1, 7), breaks=breaks, 
      labels=labels, name = "Number of treatments") +
      scale_x_discrete(name="") + coord_flip() +
      ggtitle("Name") +
      theme_gray() 

print(fp)
```

Which prints:

[image: Forest plot]
I want to add a side table where the study size (d$number) is shown next to the study name (d$author).

There is a similar example here: 
[image]

But instead of "Occupation", "Recreation", "Gender" and "OR", I want d$author and d$number shown.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, including data.

Comment: Can I upload my data sheet in here?

Comment: I suggest you read the various answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Add table of values below ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41164675/903061), [How can I add a table to ggplot output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16680063/903061).

Comment: Thanks - sure. Im new in here. Im deleting this post and I will do a new one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40265494/ggplot-grobs-align-with-tablegrob/40269943#40269943

Comment: @ChristianMirianLarsen this is duplicate, so better take the time to study the various links and then delete (or let it be closed as dupe).

Comment: Okay, sorry! I didnt realize that! Im very new to this! How can I close this as a duplicate?