# Combining a heatmap and a dendrogram in a grob plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, dendrogram, r-grid

I'm trying to plot a `heatmap` along with a row `dendrogram`, which I manipulated (pruned the number of branches), aligned using `grid.draw`.

Here's my data:

```
set.seed(10)
mat     <- matrix(rnorm(24*10,mean=1,sd=2),nrow=24,ncol=10,dimnames=list(paste("g",1:24,sep=""),paste("my.expriment.sample",1:10,sep="")))
dend    <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(mat)))
row.ord <- order.dendrogram(dend)
mat     <- matrix(mat[row.ord,],nrow=24,ncol=10,
             dimnames=list(rownames(mat)[row.ord],colnames(mat)))
mat.df  <- reshape2::melt(mat,value.name="expr",varnames=c("gene","sample"))
```

The `heatmap` part of the plot:

```
require(ggplot2)
map.plot <- ggplot(mat.df,aes(x=sample,y=gene)) + geom_tile(aes(fill=expr)) +
    scale_fill_gradient2("expr",high="darkred",low="darkblue") + theme_bw() + 
    theme(legend.key=element_blank(),legend.position="right", axis.text.y=element_blank(), axis.ticks.y=element_blank(), 
    panel.border=element_blank(), strip.background=element_blank(),  axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45,hjust=1,vjust=1), 
    legend.text=element_text(size=5), legend.title=element_text(size=8), legend.key.size=unit(0.4,"cm"))
```

Which gives:

[image]

Notice the long column labels - that's similar to what I have in reality.

Here's how I manipulate and plot the `dendrogram`:

```
depth.cutoff <- 11
dend <- cut(dend,h=depth.cutoff)$upper
require(dendextend)
gg.dend <- as.ggdend(dend)

#change vertical segments that lead to leaves
distinctColors <- function(n) {
  if (n <= 8) {
    res <- brewer.pal(n, "Set2")
  } else {
    res <- hcl(h=seq(0,(n-1)/(n),length=n)*360,c=100,l=65,fixup=TRUE)
  }
}

cluster.cols <- distinctColors(nrow(gg.dend$labels))
leaf.heights <- dplyr::filter(gg.dend$nodes,!is.na(leaf))$height
leaf.seqments.idx <- which(gg.dend$segments$yend %in% leaf.heights)
gg.dend$segments$yend[leaf.seqments.idx] <- max(gg.dend$segments$yend[leaf.seqments.idx])
gg.dend$segments$col[leaf.seqments.idx] <- cluster.cols

#change labels
gg.dend$labels$label <- 1:nrow(gg.dend$labels)
gg.dend$labels$y <- max(gg.dend$segments$yend[leaf.seqments.idx])
gg.dend$labels$x <- gg.dend$segments$x[leaf.seqments.idx]
gg.dend$labels$col <- cluster.cols
dend.plot <- ggplot(gg.dend,labels=F)+scale_y_reverse()+coord_flip()+annotate("text",size=10,hjust=0,x=gg.dend$label$x,y=gg.dend$label$y,label=gg.dend$label$label,colour=gg.dend$label$col)
```

which gives:

[image]

Trying to follow [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370853/align-ggplot2-plots-vertically/17371177#17371177), I do:

```
require(gtable)
plot.grob <- ggplotGrob(dend.plot)
plot.grob <- gtable_add_cols(plot.grob,unit(1,"cm"))
plot.grob <- gtable_add_grob(plot.grob,ggplotGrob(map.plot),t=1,l=ncol(plot.grob),b=1,r=ncol(plot.grob))
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(plot.grob)
```

But this comes out messed up:
[image]

Any idea how to get `dend.plot` aligned with the `heatmap` part of `map.plot` such that the lower branch of `dend.plot` is bottom aligned with the the `heatmap` and not the bottom of the column labels?

Comment: `Error in labs(y = lab.row, x = lab.col) : object 'lab.row' not found`

Comment: Sorry about that. I deleted that from my post.

Comment: It would seem more straightforward to add the dendrogram to the heatmap's gtable

Comment: A lot is going on in your question. (1) consider using dendextend::color_branches
   (2) generally you can combine a dendrogram with a heatmap (such as in gplots::heatmap.2) by supplying your dendrogram to the Rowv parameter. You can see that in these examples here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/vignettes/introduction.html#gplots  (3) lastly, have a look at the heatmaply package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/heatmaply/vignettes/heatmaply.html

Answer (score 1):

`cowplot` is super good at aligning ggplots.

```
library(cowplot)
plot_grid(dend.plot, map.plot, align = 'h')
```

[image]

Also, try to have a bit shorter example (why do I need a super detailed `theme` call?), and make sure it actually runs in a clean session.

Comment: One more question: how do you eliminate the large margin between the dendrogram and heatmap? I tried adding plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,0),"cm" to theme of both map.plot and dend.plot and play around with scale and rel_widths in plot_grid but none seem to really work

Comment: Nevermind. Figured it out - need to provide negative values in plot.margin