# Aligning / setting width of margin/figure region in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to position several plots below each other and I want the widths of the margin and figure regions to be identical, so they align neatly. Note, that I need two single plots, not one joint plot. I want to save each one in a separate PNG file. I just want their structure (margin, figure region size) to be identical.

```
library(ggplot2)

d <- data.frame(label=c("some very longe label with lots of text", 
                        "another long label with lots of text", 
                        "short", 
                        "also short",
                        "                                     short", 
                        "                                also short"), 
                        x = 1:6)

ggplot(d[1:2, ], aes(label, x)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")  + coord_flip()
ggplot(d[3:4, ], aes(label, x)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")  + coord_flip()
```

[image]
[image]

What I want is plot 2 to have the same left margin width as in plot 1, more or less like below, of course without adding extra blanks ;)

[image]

In base graphics I would just set `par("mar")` accordingly.

**How can I achieve this in ggplot?**

Comment: please see links at this comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41230345/ggplot2-change-plot-areas-for-same-size-plots-in-multiplot#comment69662588_41230345

Comment: https://github.com/baptiste/egg#setting-panel-size

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the answer from the [last link from the comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489250/specifying-ggplot2-panel-width#5492301),
you can equate the widths of the plots. The only difference from that answer is that they are not combined.

So for your plots

```
library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot(d[1:2, ], aes(label, x)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")  + coord_flip()
p2 <- ggplot(d[3:4, ], aes(label, x)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")  + coord_flip()
```

Equate widths of plot

```
library(grid)
gl <- lapply(list(p1,p2), ggplotGrob)  
wd <- do.call(unit.pmax, lapply(gl, "[[", 'widths'))
gl <- lapply(gl, function(x) {
        x[['widths']] = wd
        x})
```

Plot

```
grid.newpage(); grid.draw(gl[[1]])
grid.newpage(); grid.draw(gl[[2]])
```

Which produces:

Plot 1

[image]

Plot 2

[image]

Comment: great, thanks! width is key here. Do you happen to have a good reference to the structure of the ggplot figure regions, like this one for base graphics: http://www.melissaclarkson.com/resources/R_guides/documents/figure_layout_Ver1.pdf

Comment: @MarkHeckmann ; Baptiste really is the person to help with this. But perhaps `expose_layout` from his [`egg package`](https://github.com/baptiste/egg) would be useful. So use `p1 <- qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars, colour=cyl) +  ggtitle("facetted plot") ;
g = expose_layout(p1) ; g$widths` . Then see how the widths align with the exposed layout plot. (widths go from left to right) (also look at `names(g)` for other things to examine)