# In a grid of ggplot patchwork/cowplot/etc., how to align *only the outer boundaries* of the plots?

Tags: r, ggplot2, alignment, cowplot, patchwork

I have several plots with lengthy legends: (example plot using `iris`, NOT my actual plot)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

theme_template <- theme_classic() +
  theme( # add border all around plot
    panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA, linewidth = 1)
  )

p1 <- iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_discrete(
    breaks = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"),
    labels = c("Setosa", "Versicolor", "VirginicaVirginicaVirginicaVirginica")
  ) +
  theme_template

p2 <- iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_template

p3 <- iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_violin(aes(fill = Species), scale = "width") +
  geom_boxplot(width = .2, outlier.color = NA, fill = "black") +
  theme_template +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    aspect.ratio = 1
  )

p4 <- iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = Petal.Width)) +
  geom_violin(aes(fill = Species), scale = "width") +
  geom_boxplot(width = .2, outlier.color = NA, fill = "black") +
  theme_template +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    aspect.ratio = 1
  )

p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + plot_layout(ncol = 2, heights = c(1, 1, 1, 1))
```

When put together using `patchwork` or `cowplot`, it always ends like this:

[image: A grid of four plots, every outline aligning with each other]

Because of the lengthy legend, there's a huge gap between two bottom plots. Due to limitation of my actual dataset and formatting code, I'm not allowed to group the legends together or put them elsewhere not so hindering, and I can't make the wording any shorter.

I wish to achieve something like this:

[image: A grid of four plots, only the outer boundaries were aligned]

Is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Align multiple plots in ggplot2 when some have legends and others don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41569817/align-multiple-plots-in-ggplot2-when-some-have-legends-and-others-dont)

Comment: @benson23 sadly it doesn't. I can probably make right border of bottom left graph align with the rightmost reach of top left plot legend. But that's not what I wanted.

Comment: Does adding `theme( legend.position = "bottom",  legend.direction = "vertical", aspect.ratio = 1 )` to plots 1 and 2 help?

Comment: @Peter It certainly helps and looks good for me. Unfortunately, the original plots are meant for journals, and some reviewers are annoyed to find legends down there. So unless I could came up with a really really well-written response, I would like a solution with the legends stay the way as they were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to sacrifice the aspect ratio, you can use `(p1 | p2) / (p3 | p4)`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

theme_template <- theme_classic() +
  theme( # add border all around plot
    panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA, linewidth = 1)
  )

p1 <- iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_discrete(
    breaks = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"),
    labels = c("Setosa", "Versicolor", "VirginicaVirginicaVirginicaVirginica")
  ) +
  theme_template

p2 <- iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_template

p3 <- iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_violin(aes(fill = Species), scale = "width") +
  geom_boxplot(width = .2, outlier.color = NA, fill = "black") +
  theme_template +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none"
  )

p4 <- iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = Petal.Width)) +
  geom_violin(aes(fill = Species), scale = "width") +
  geom_boxplot(width = .2, outlier.color = NA, fill = "black") +
  theme_template +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none"
  )

(p1 | p2) / (p3 | p4)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Yeah, I also figured out it could be realized if I ditch the `aspect.ratio` arguments. Can't understand why.

Comment: I think the following documentation might clarify some: https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/layout.html#fixed-aspect-plots